# AsyncLocal unexpectedly revives its value - no async/await is involved

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.8

This is a convoluted situation, please bear with me.

I have a `BagOfProperties` class and I want to make an instance of it `AsyncLocal`, like this

```cs
private readonly static System.Threading.AsyncLocal<BagOfProperties> _bag = new();
private static BagOfProperties Bag => _bag.Value ??= new BagOfProperties();
```

Everywhere in code I'm now accessing the properties via that `Bag` variable, nicely making all of them AsyncLocal.

Now, for *reasons*, I want to be able to reset those properties. Easily done:

```cs
private static void ResetBag()
{
    _bag.Value = null;
}
```

Since the `_bag` is an `AsyncLocal`, this is safe to do anytime, existing tasks using the bag will still have access to old values, but new tasks will call the constructor first.

This part works.

Next step is, I want to call `ResetBag` from WinForms' `Application.Idle` event handler. This is where it breaks (on some racing condition - depending on where I place breakpoints, it might work).

What happens is, `_bag.Value` is set to `null`, but then we go the stack up until `System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal` where `System.Threading.ExecutionContextSwitcher.Undo()` is called and the `_bag.Value` is restored to the previous version.

And there isn't even a single async call on the entire stack!

I've added following ValueChangedHandler.

```cs
private static void ValueChangedHandler(System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<BagOfProperties> asyncLocalValueChangedArgs)
{
    if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == 1)
    {
      var previousValue = asyncLocalValueChangedArgs.PreviousValue;
      var currentValue = asyncLocalValueChangedArgs.CurrentValue;
      var contextChanged = asyncLocalValueChangedArgs.ThreadContextChanged;
    }
}
```

I'm only interested in `ManagedThreadId == 1` because right now there is no async in my code, but stuff happens in 3rd party components on other threads.

The stack when the value is set to null looks like this (asterixes are mine).

```
 MyHelper.dll!MyApp.Class1.ValueChangedHandler(System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<MyApp.Class1.BagOfProperties> asyncLocalValueChangedArgs = {System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<MyApp.Class1.BagOfProperties>}) Line 28    C#
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.AsyncLocal<MyApp.Class1.BagOfProperties>.System.Threading.IAsyncLocal.OnValueChanged(object previousValueObj, object currentValueObj, bool contextChanged)    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SetLocalValue(System.Threading.IAsyncLocal local, object newValue, bool needChangeNotifications)    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.AsyncLocal<System.__Canon>.Value.set(System.__Canon value)    Unknown
 MyHelper.dll!MyApp.Class1.ResetBag() Line 21    C#
 [Native to Managed Transition]    
 [Managed to Native Transition]    
 * MyFramework.Win.dll!MyFramework.MyUtils.Application_Idle(object sender = {System.Threading.Thread}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 3872    C#
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RaiseIdle(System.EventArgs e)    Unknown
 MyFramework.Win.dll!MyFramework.MyUtils.TrackPopupMenu.AnonymousMethod__136_1() Line 3697    C#
 [Native to Managed Transition]    
 [Managed to Native Transition]    
 mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(object obj)    Unknown
 * mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 MyFramework.Win.dll!MyFramework.MyForm.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message}) Line 4309    C#
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 49641, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    Unknown
 [Native to Managed Transition]    
 [Managed to Native Transition]    
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason = -1, int pvLoopData = 0)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = -1, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext})    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)    Unknown
 MyApp.exe!MyApp.Program.Main() Line 25    C#
```

The stack when the value is restored looks like this.

```
 MyHelper.dll!MyApp.Class1.ValueChangedHandler(System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<MyApp.Class1.BagOfProperties> asyncLocalValueChangedArgs = {System.Threading.AsyncLocalValueChangedArgs<MyApp.Class1.BagOfProperties>}) Line 28    C#
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.AsyncLocal<MyApp.Class1.BagOfProperties>.System.Threading.IAsyncLocal.OnValueChanged(object previousValueObj, object currentValueObj, bool contextChanged)    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.OnAsyncLocalContextChanged(System.Threading.ExecutionContext previous = {System.Threading.ExecutionContext}, System.Threading.ExecutionContext current = {System.Threading.ExecutionContext})    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContextSwitcher.Undo()    Unknown
 * mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 MyFramework.Win.dll!MyFramework.MyForm.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message}) Line 4309    C#
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 49641, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    Unknown
 [Native to Managed Transition]    
 [Managed to Native Transition]    
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason = -1, int pvLoopData = 0)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = -1, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext})    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)    Unknown
 MyApp.exe!MyApp.Program.Main() Line 25    C#
```

Is there a way to ensure the `ResetBag` will run with the correct `ExecutionContext`**?** As an aside note, implementation of `AsyncLocal.Value` f.e. [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/AsyncLocal.cs,35).

App is .NET Framework 4.8, Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use `AsyncLocal<T>` in a way it wasn't designed. Async local values flow "down" the call stack, never "up". And ideally, they're immutable, which forces code to set `Value` instead of relying on side effects (which are tricky to think about with async local).

It sounds like what you want is something more like snapshot semantics; I'd look into System.Collections.Immutable (sounds like `ImmutableDictionary` will serve you well). Have each task lock-and-copy the current value (lazy creating if necessary) and then use its local copy; have your idle handler lock-and-copy the current value and set it to `null`. I don't see a need for an `AsyncLocal<T>` with the current description of the problem.

Comment: "Async local values flow "down" the call stack, never "up"." - I know that, but this only applies to async stack, or, more specifically, it flows down the tasks and never up. In my case, there are no tasks involved at all (yet).

Comment: @TymurGubayev: the "async stack" isn't the only place execution contexts are used, as you discovered. Your code is assuming asynclocal == global in the absence of tasks, but this is not the case. AsyncLocal was designed to be flowed down stacks, and trying to use it as a global will result in surprising behavior like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, refactoring is not really an option for me, due to other requirements. Is there a way to determine what causes the change of execution context, or maybe a list somewhere? Alternatively, is there a way to force the code to execute on the "top-most" execution context?

Comment: @TymurGubayev: There is no list. Frameworks are free to use the execution context as they wish, although they *must* use the execution context in some situations for security reasons. It's possible you may be able to get the code to run on the topmost by capturing it before your message loop starts and restoring it when running the code. But I don't think that would solve this problem; your code would end up nesting that ExCtx below the one provided by your framework. I think refactoring is the only realistic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take same approach as dotnet team took with [HttpContextAccessor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs), so you create a wrapper around the `BagOfProperties` and save its reference on the `AsyncLocal` instead of the actual `BagOfProperties`.

```
private class BagOfPropertiesWrapper
{
    public BagOfProperties BagOfProperties { get; set; } = new();
}

private static AsyncLocal<BagOfPropertiesWrapper> _bagWrapper = new();

private static BagOfProperties Bag()
{
    _bagWrapper.Value ??= new BagOfPropertiesWrapper();

    return _bagWrapper.Value.BagOfProperties;
}

private static void ResetBag()
{
    if (_bagWrapper.Value is not null)
    {
        _bagWrapper.Value.BagOfProperties = null;
    }
}
```

So now when you do a `ResetBag`, you will be clearing `BagOfProperties` which was referenced from `BagOfPropertiesWrapper` which is flowed by AsyncLocal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the link, good to know people are using this in at least a somewhat similar manner. And I do think this will solve the immediate problem I have but, I think, it will also introduce problems once there actually are tasks involved: using object indirection would reset it across all tasks and threads (or, rather, ExecutionContexts), which isn't something we want.

Comment: Yep that's true, that's what I had in mind when suggesting this approach, but maybe it helps to find a way around :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause of the undesired change in the `ExecutionContext` and also a workaround for my case.

The cause lies in this part of the stack.

```
MyHelper.dll!MyApp.Class1.ResetBag() Line 21    C#
[Native to Managed Transition]    
[Managed to Native Transition]    
MyFramework.Win.dll!MyFramework.MyUtils.Application_Idle(object sender = {System.Threading.Thread}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 3872    C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RaiseIdle(System.EventArgs e)    Unknown
MyFramework.Win.dll!MyFramework.MyUtils.TrackPopupMenu.AnonymousMethod__136_1() Line 3697    C#
[Native to Managed Transition]    
[Managed to Native Transition]    
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme)    Unknown
```

It looks that way because, for unrelated reasons, I have the following code.

```cs
aForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Application.RaiseIdle(EventArgs.Empty)));
```

It turns out, `Control.BeginInvoke` has an (in my case undesired) side effect of changing the `ExecutionContext`, making the callback use a copy of the "main" `ExecutionContext` and not the main thing itself.

I've changed it to the following.

```cs
var flowControl = System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
f.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    flowControl.Undo();
    Application.RaiseIdle(EventArgs.Empty);
}));
```

This solves my issue, but may introduce a problem should a `Task` be created between the calls to `SuppressFlow` and `Undo`: that task would then unexpectedly operate on the main version of the `ExecutionContext`/`AsyncLocal`s (i.e. the inverse of my current problem).